# Label for point in plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

So this is sort of a question about a posted solution. I was trying to put some data labels on points in a matplotlib scatterplot I have. I was trying to imitate the solution here:

[Is there a matplotlib equivalent of MATLAB's datacursormode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652439/is-there-a-matplotlib-equivalent-of-matlabs-datacursormode)

within `def __call__(self, event):` I get a failure at line:

```
xdata, ydata = event.artist.get_data()
AttributeError: 'CircleCollection' object has no attribute 'get_data'
```

Looking to the docs here: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html#module-matplotlib.artist

I see no method `get_data(`) for Artist. Is this just something that has been deprecated or did I miss something? If it has been, anyone know of how else to get an equivalent call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the rest of the code in `__call__` you'll see `xdata` and `ydata` are never used. You can simply delete the line

```
xdata, ydata = event.artist.get_data()
```

and the rest of Joe's beautiful code works just fine.

Comment: Yikes, how did I miss that. I guess I breezed over it and saw the qualified xdata and ydata refs. Thanks