# Python and Remove annotation from figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot-annotations

I am using matplotlib inside of a wxpython GUI.  In short, I have plotted a bunch of data.  I then click on a data point (using DataCursor found at:

[Is there a matplotlib equivalent of MATLAB's datacursormode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652439/is-there-a-matplotlib-equivalent-of-matlabs-datacursormode)

or

[Pop up annotations on matplotlib within wxPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11162401/pop-up-annotations-on-matplotlib-within-wxpython)

The second link is my actual implementation.  I refrense the datacursor class from other classes.  What i'm wondering, how do i remove the annotation by clicking an event button?  For instance, I have an event button that updates my scatter plot (by using plot_handle.set_data and not by clearing the figure).  However, the annotation remains exactly where it was regardless if the point is there or not.  How do i remove it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most matplotlib objects have a `remove()` function (I think it is inherited from `Artist`).  Just call that on the object you want to remove.

Edit:

If you have

```
dc = DataCursor(...) # what ever aruguements you give it
# bunch of code
dc.annotation.remove()
del dc
plt.draw() # need to redraw to make remove visible
```

Python has no notion of 'private' attributes, so you can just reach inside you object and call remove on the annotation.   See [tutorial on classes for more details](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html).

The down side of this is that now you have an object is a strange state.  If you have any other references to it, they might behave badly.  If you want to keep the `DataCursor` object around you can modify the `annotation` object using it's `set_*` functions or change it's visibility to temporarily hide it ([doc](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text))

Comment: but how do i determine the name of the object?  That is what i seem to be having trouble with since it is created in another class (another "self" -- if that makes sense?)

Comment: @mcfly I would recommend (re)reading http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html .

Answer (score 1):

You need to add it like an artist to delete it like an artist

```
arrow2 = matplotlib.text.Annotation("I love it",xy=(0.5,0.5),xycoords='data',arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="-")) 
ax2.add_artist(arrow2) 
arrow2.remove()
```