# How do you make scatterplot annotations appear on mouse click when scatterplot is based on dataframe and involves colour-coded data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, dataframe

I have a dataset:

```
a   b   c   d
10-Apr-86   Jimmy   1   Silly.doc
11-Apr-86   Minnie  2   Lala.doc
12-Apr-86   Jimmy   3   Goofy.doc
13-Apr-86   Minnie  4   Hilarious.doc
14-Apr-86   Jimmy   5   Joyous.doc
15-Apr-86   Eliot   6   Crackingup.doc
16-Apr-86   Jimmy   7   Funny.doc
17-Apr-86   Eliot   8   Happy.doc
18-Apr-86   Minnie  9   Mirthful.doc
```

Using the following code in python 2.7.12..

```
df = (pd.read_csv('python.csv'))
df_wanted = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    index='a',
    columns='b',
    values='c')

df_wanted.index = pd.to_datetime(df_wanted.index)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.scatter(df_wanted.index, df_wanted['Jimmy'], s=50, c='b', marker="s")
ax1.scatter(df_wanted.index,df_wanted['Minnie'], s=50, c='r', marker="o")
ax1.scatter(df_wanted.index,df_wanted['Eliot'], s=50, c='g', marker="8")
plt.legend(loc='upper left');

for k, v in df.set_index('a').iterrows():
    plt.text(k, v['c'], v['d'])
plt.show()
```

.. I can create the following visualization in matplotlib:

[image]

The problem: this is only a toy dataset.  When I apply this code to my real dataset, which has more than 3000 points, all the data labels blend together in a black illegible block.

I would like to avoid this problem by using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306519/get-data-from-plot-with-matplotlib) to make the data labels appear when they are clicked.

The issue I'm having is with this part of the above-mentioned code,

```
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[6,7,8,9,10]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
scat = ax.scatter(x, y)
DataCursor(scat, x, y)
plt.show()
```

Obviously, I need to replace the "x" and "y" with my pivot table columns, but I don't know how to make `scat = ax.scatter(x, y)` or `DataCursor(scat, x, y)` work with my data.

I tried the following

```
scat = ax1.scatter(df_wanted.index, df_wanted['Minnie'], s=50, c='b', marker="s")
scat1 = ax1.scatter(df_wanted.index,df_wanted['Jimmy'], s=50, c='r', marker="o")
scat2 = ax1.scatter(df_wanted.index,df_wanted['Eliot'], s=50, c='g', marker="8")

DataCursor(scat,df_wanted.index,df_wanted['Minnie'])
DataCursor(scat1,df_wanted.index,df_wanted['Jimmy'])
DataCursor(scat2,df_wanted.index,df_wanted['Eliot'])
plt.show()
```

But I get this error `TypeError: Invalid Type Promotion`

UPDATE: I used the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/possible-to-make-labels-appear-when-hovering-over-a-point-in-matplotlib) to get the doc name in the console:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
import numpy as npy
from numpy.random import rand
import pandas as pd

df = (pd.read_csv('python.csv'))
df_wanted = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    index='a',
    columns='b',
    values='c')

df_wanted.index = pd.to_datetime(df_wanted.index)


if 1: # picking on a scatter plot     (matplotlib.collections.RegularPolyCollection)

    c = 'r'
    c1 = 'b'
    c2 = 'g'
    s = 85 
    y = df_wanted['Minnie']
    z = df_wanted['Jimmy']
    f = df_wanted['Eliot']
    x = df_wanted.index
    def onpick3(event):
        ind = event.ind
        print npy.take(df['d'], ind)

    fig = figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    col = ax1.scatter(x, y, s, c, picker=True)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    col = ax1.scatter(x, z, s, c1, picker=True)
    ax3 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    col = ax1.scatter(x, f, s, c2, picker=True)
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    #fig.savefig('pscoll.eps')
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick3)

show()
```

The problem now is that the document name being returned is not accurate.  I think the problem is that the ind number is for each individual series.  I need a way to combine all the series, and assign an ind number to their total.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.  I realized I wanted to follow this example ([Matplotlib scatterplot; colour as a function of a third variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8202605/matplotlib-scatterplot-colour-as-a-function-of-a-third-variable)), but needed to first make a single list of x values and a single list of y values, rather than individual lists of x and y values for each series.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
import numpy as npy
from numpy.random import rand
import pandas as pd

df = (pd.read_csv('python.csv')) #upload dataset

df['a'] = pd.to_datetime(df['a']) #convert date column to useable format

x = list(df['a'].values.flatten()) #get dataframe column data in list format
y= list(df['c'].values.flatten()) #get dataframe column data in list format

var_names = list(df['b'].values.flatten()) #get dataframe column data in list format
var_names1 = list(set(var_names)) #get unique values from column b (names) 


d = {var_names1[n]:n for n in range(len(var_names1))} #generate dictionary that assigns number to each unique name in col B



namesAsNumbers = [d[z] for z in var_names] #replace names with numbers in column B

c=  namesAsNumbers



if 1: # picking on a scatter plot (matplotlib.collections.RegularPolyCollection) # user picks point on scatter

    def onpick3(event):
        ind = event.ind
        print npy.take(df['d'], ind) #print the document name associated with the point that's been picked

    fig = figure()
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
    col = ax1.scatter(x, y, s= 100, c=c, picker=True)
    #fig.savefig('pscoll.eps')
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick3)
    plt.legend()
show()
```

Only problem I still have: can't seem to get a legend to appear.