# How to have all values/numbers in x-axis (matplotlib)?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I was doing some analysis and then I want to plot the data, everything is ok, no errors - but I want to ask how I can add to my code a setting, which extends x-axis, thus I can see all numbers from 0 to 115 (now I can only guess if the dot very below is 17th or 18th)

This is the line from my complex code, where I plot my data from PCA using matplotlib (here I am plotting the 1st pca):

```
plt.plot(data [:, 0], "-o", )
```

[image: and here is my graph]

Comment: You can enable the grid, or zoom in. What result are you expecting, exactly?

Comment: I would like to have written al numbers at x-axis, as "1,2,3,4,5,...." and then I could indetify the dots very below, because now I cant be sure which "number" at x-axis are they

Comment: You could enable the minor ticks and the grid to see better, by using `ax = plt.gca()` `ax.grid(True, "both", "x")`.

Comment: If you label each datapoint it would look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RTjc.png). Since this is of course not what you want, please be clear about the expected result. See first comment.

Comment: Ok, if it would look like that (definitely not what I want it to look like) - then I would also need extend the x-axis, right? to be able to read numbers at x-axis

Comment: Please use something like paint or Photoshop to draw what you want to do

Comment: Maybe you want to look at [make labels appear when hovering over a point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/possible-to-make-labels-appear-when-hovering-over-a-point-in-matplotlib) or maybe [get data from plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13306519/get-data-from-plot-with-matplotlib)

Comment: Do you use an interactive backend (i.e., you have a window that appears on the screen, containing the graph) or you plot directly to a file and later use an image/document viewer to inspect your plot?  In the first case it is possible to interact with  the graph, especially zooming and panning into it --- when you zoom in, also the labels in the axes are adjusted accordingly and you can clearly see the abscissa of any particular point...

Comment: You can make your figure bigger, but to make 115 ticks all show up and not overlap (assuming a font size of 10 pts), you'd need to make the figure about 47 inches wide.