# How to prevent a matplotlib annotation being clipped by other axes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot in matplotlib with multiple subplots(axes), and I want to annotate the points within the axes. However, subsequent axes overlay annotations from previous axes (eg annotation on subplot(4,4,1) goes under subplot(4,4,2)). I have set the annotation zorder nice and high, but to no avail :/

I've used a modified version of [Joe Kington's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325565/joe-kington) awesome [DataCursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652439/is-there-a-matplotlib-equivalent-of-matlabs-datacursormode/4674445#4674445) for the annotations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here's an example:
[image]

Comment: Hmmm... There should be an easy way to do this, but I can't figure it out...  If you plot the text in the figure instead of the axes (e.g. using `fig.text`), it will always appear above. As long as it's in the axes, it will get overdrawn by other subplots, as `zorder` only applies _inside_ an axes.  I can think of some nasty hacks to replace all of the `annotate` calls with `fig.text` but it isn't pretty... There should be a better way...

Comment: Incidentally, glad you found the DataCursor snippet useful!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to do it is to pop the text created by `annotate` out of the axes and add it to the figure.  This way it will be displayed on top of all of the subplots.

As a quick example of the problem you're having:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=5)
plt.setp(axes.flat, xticks=[], yticks=[], zorder=0)

ax = axes[0,0]
ax.annotate('Testing this out and seeing what happens', xy=(0.5, 0.5), 
            xytext=(1.1, .5), textcoords='axes fraction', zorder=100)

plt.show()
```

[image]

If we just pop the text object out of the axes and add it to the figure instead, it will be on top:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=5)
plt.setp(axes.flat, xticks=[], yticks=[], zorder=0)

ax = axes[0,0]
ax.annotate('Testing this out and seeing what happens', xy=(0.5, 0.5), 
            xytext=(1.1, .5), textcoords='axes fraction', zorder=100)

fig.texts.append(ax.texts.pop())

plt.show()
```

[image]

You mentioned the `DataCursor` snippet, and there you'd want to change the `annotate` method:

```
def annotate(self, ax):
    """Draws and hides the annotation box for the given axis "ax"."""
    annotation = ax.annotate(self.template, xy=(0, 0), ha='right',
            xytext=self.offsets, textcoords='offset points', va='bottom',
            bbox=dict(boxstyle='round,pad=0.5', fc='yellow', alpha=0.5),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0')
            )
    # Put the annotation in the figure instead of the axes so that it will be on
    # top of other subplots.
    ax.figure.texts.append(ax.texts.pop())

    annotation.set_visible(False)
    return annotation
```

I haven't tested the last bit, but it should work...

Comment: Thanks heaps, Joe :) That worked perfectly!
And thanks for DataCursor, too. Love it!

Answer (score 1):

A quicker solution would be to change the `zorder` of the **plots** instead of actually bringing the text out of the plot itself (which by the way didn't work for me).

So for this case in which the annotations extend to the right/bottom:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=5, ncols=3)

num_plots = len(axes) * len(axes[0])

for row in axes:
    for column in row:
        column.zorder = num_plots
        num_plots -= 1
```

Each following plot (left to right/up to bottom) inside the figure would be "behind" the previous one, so the annotations are not overlapped.