# Annotation in corner of plot ignores 'alpha' argument

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting subplots side by side and would like to designate them respectively as 'a' and 'b'. I figure that the top right corner would be a good spot for that.

When I use matplotlib's `annotate` like:

```
props = dict(boxstyle="round", fc='white',alpha = 1)
ax.annotate("b", (1, 1), xycoords = 'axes fraction', verticalalignment = "center", horizontalalignment='center', size=14, bbox = props)
```

It places the textbox correctly but the textbox is transparent:
[image]

Same happens if I try to use matplotlib's `text` instead of `annotate`. Do you know what is happening ?

Comment: No, but thanks to your comment I ended up on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831824/how-to-prevent-a-matplotlib-annotation-being-clipped-by-other-axes where someone actually posted the solution for that. One has to pop the text out before actually putting on the figure.

Answer (score 0):

I found out  here ([How to prevent a matplotlib annotation being clipped by other axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13831824/how-to-prevent-a-matplotlib-annotation-being-clipped-by-other-axes)) that one should pop the text out before adding it to the figure. The following snipet solved the issue.

```
props = dict(boxstyle="round", fc='white',alpha = 1)
ax.annotate("b", xy=(1, 1), textcoords='axes fraction', verticalalignment = "center", horizontalalignment='center', size=14, bbox = props)
fig.texts.append(ax.texts.pop())
```