# Ploting and viewing (x,y) points

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm working with data consisting in 2M points of aceleration in time, what im doing is apllying FFT to de dataset and ploting it to see behaviours.

I did it with Matplotlib but i have the problem that i can not see or select any point to see to wich (x,y) value correspond, too that i trully need (in matlab plot you can do it with a plot tool). I tried Bokeh but the problem is that is too slow plotting and ive been having some issues showing the plots (sometimes it plot, sometimes dont).

So my question is is there is any way to select (x,y) value (by clicking) in Matplotlib  or if there is any plot tool to do this in a fast way?
[this is the ploting data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WLE7.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4674445/190597

Comment: i saw it but i dont think is the best way to do it.