# python plotting and image viewing library with equivalent of MATLABs datatips

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, spyder, datatip

Currently, I use MATLAB extensively for analyzing experimental scientific data (mostly time traces and images). However, again and again I keep running into fundamental problems with the MATLAB language and I would like to make the switch to python. One feature of matlab is holding me back however: its ability to add datatips to plots and images.

For a line plot the datatip is a window next to one of the data points that shows its coordinates. This is very useful to quickly see where datapoints are and what their value is. Of course this can also be done by inspecting the vectors that were used to plot the line, but that is slightly more cumbersome and becomes a headache when trying to analyze loads of data. E.g. let's say we quickly want to know for what value of x, y=0.6. Moving the datatip around will give a rough estimate very quickly.

[image: line plot with datatip]

For images, the datatip shows the x and y coordinates, but also the greyscale value (called index by MATLAB) and the RGB color. I'm mainly interested in the greyscale value here. Suppose we want to know the coordinates of the bottom tip of the pupil of the cat's eye. A datatip allows to simply click that point and copy the coordinates (either manually or programmatically). Alternatively, one would have to write some image processing script to find this pixel location. For a one time analysis that is not worthwhile.

[image: image with datatip]

The plotting library for python that I'm most familiar with and that is commonly called the most flexible is matplotlib. An old [stock overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4652439/is-there-a-matplotlib-equivalent-of-matlabs-) seems to indicate that this can be done using `mpldatacursor` and another module seems to be `mplcursors`. These libraries do not seem to be compatible with Spyder, however, limiting their usability. Also, I imagine many python programmers would be using a feature like datatips, so it seems odd to have to rely on a 3rd party module.

Now on to the actual question: Is there any module (or simple piece of code that I could put in my personal library) to get the equivalent of MATLAB's datatips in all figures generated by a python script?