# Is it possible to show tooltips on a networkx graph?

Tags: python, tooltip, networkx

I have a simple graph with a lot of points, so I don't want to show labels for all of them. But I do want to be able to tell which is which, via tooltips.

Is it possible to add/show tooltips using networkx?

Here's my code:

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.Graph()
g.add_node(1, label="descriptive label")
nx.draw(g)
```

I'd like "descriptive label" to show up as a tooltip. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NetworkX does not have this built in, NetworkX uses matplotlib underneath so you could try the suggestion here:

[Point and line tooltips in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453143/point-and-line-tooltips-in-matplotlib)

and adapt it to your code, hope this helps.