# Pop-up plot label on mouse-over event in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, tkinter

I am working on a *python 2.7+matplotlib+tkinter* project where I need to plot up to 60 plots on 1 figure (I can show/hide them then by pressing corresponding legend title and do some other interactive stuff). What I want is to get an annotation box on mouse-over event with the label of current plot. I was thinking about [text annotation](http://matplotlib.org/users/annotations_intro.html), but I haven't found any ways to do it interactively.

If it is crucial for an answer - I am working with `step` and `scatter` figures. I am ready to provide any information needed, for now I just can't think of something necessary to post here (in terms of source code)

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/possible-to-make-labels-appear-when-hovering-over-a-point-in-matplotlib) question

Comment: Thank you! Haven't found it for some reason.

Comment: Just to plug my own project: Have a look at `mpldatacursor` https://github.com/joferkington/mpldatacursor as well.  If you'd like the annotation to pop up on mouse-over instead of when the artist (line, etc) is clicked on, then just use `datacursor(hover=True)`. You'll probably want to control the text displayed with the `formatter` kwarg.  In your case, it might be as simple as `datacursor(formatter='{label}'.format, hover=True)`.