# When hovering over a point, show text. Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know that a solution to what I am asking is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/possible-to-make-labels-appear-when-hovering-over-a-point-in-matplotlib).

The situation is the following:

I have a matrix whose first row is a list of identification numbers. Each column of the matrix (there are M columns) is the identification number of the column plus a vector of N components. I take each of these vectors and perform clustering. Once I get the clusters in the N-dimensional space I reduce the space with PCA to get a 2-dim space in which I can plot the vectors.

There are K clusters, each of them containing some of the M vectors, that after PCA are 2-dim vectors. I save these M 2-dim vectors in groups corresponding to the K clusters, then I plot each group with a different colour to distinguish them.

I understand that if I plot a scatter plot with data `X=[x1,...,xn]`, `Y=[y1,...,yn]` and I write `picker=true`, then when I click on the jth point in the plot, there will be returned an index j. Of course when I plot K times (to plot the K clusters), there will be K points that have index = 0. This is problematic for the following reason:

The identification numbers can be put into a list `ids = thematrix[0, :]` (the first row). My idea is that when I click a point I want to get an index that correctly relates the point to the id. But since many points have index = 0,1,..., then I click many points and I get the same id.

Here's the code I am using to plot the clusters and to get the index.

```
for i in xrange(len(useful_clusters)):
        cluster = useful_clusters[i]
        colour = colours[i]
        ax.scatter(cluster[:, 0], cluster[:, 1], color=colour, marker='o', s=np.pi * 3 ** 2, alpha=0.95, lw=0, picker=True)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick3)
```

How could I plot every single point in the order given by `ids` so that when I click on any point I correctly get the id corresponding to that point?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: The `event` object you get from the callback should know what artist it belongs to which you can in turn ask for it's x/y data as the linked answer shows.

Comment: For the Artists you get back from `scatter` the values are in `sc.get_offsets()`.

Comment: You can also pass a `label` and `uid` kwargs to `scatter`, both of which can be used in the pick event to uniquely identify which point was clicked on.