# How to regain control using mpl_disconnect() to end custom event_handling in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want the use the mpl_disconnect() function to regain control when some GUI is finished getting input. I cannot get mpl_disconnect() to work in any situation I've tried.

For illustration, I have this example from the Matplotlib documentation on event handling. This program lets the user draw a line. 
I've just added three lines of code (`if event.button==3`....).  Thus, when the user clicks the right mouse button, the handler should quit.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class LineBuilder:
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.line = line
        self.xs = list(line.get_xdata())
        self.ys = list(line.get_ydata())
        self.cid = line.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self)

    def __call__(self, event):
        print 'click', event
        if event.button==3:
            event.canvas.mpl_disconnect(event.canvas.manager.key_press_handler_id)
            return
        if event.inaxes!=self.line.axes: return
        self.xs.append(event.xdata)
        self.ys.append(event.ydata)
        self.line.set_data(self.xs, self.ys)
        self.line.figure.canvas.draw()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('click to build line segments')
line, = ax.plot([0], [0])  # empty line
linebuilder = LineBuilder(line)

plt.show()
print("I'm back!")
```

What I experience is that after I click the right button (which does not extend the line), the program does not stop. Instead, I can continue building the line with the left mouse key.

How can I disengage the event handler? 
Update:  ... and regain control, e.g. get to the final print statement.

Comment: I think you want to be using `mpl_disconnect(self.cid)` ?

Comment: That does better, but still doesn't return control to my code ("I'm back"). (Also, why is key_press_handler_id different from self.cid?)

Comment: That is because `plt.show` is still blocking.  You will get control back when you close the window and the GUI event loop stops running.

Comment: and `key_press_handler_id` is (iirc) the id for the default keypress handler ('k', 'l' for log, 'ctrl-w' to quit, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class LineBuilder:
    def __init__(self, line):
        self.line = line
        self.xs = list(line.get_xdata())
        self.ys = list(line.get_ydata())
        self.cid = line.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self)

    def __call__(self, event):
        print('click', vars(event))
        if event.button==3:
            print('clean up')
            event.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.cid)
            return
        if event.inaxes != self.line.axes:
            return
        self.xs.append(event.xdata)
        self.ys.append(event.ydata)
        self.line.set_data(self.xs, self.ys)
        self.line.figure.canvas.draw_idle()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_title('click to build line segments')
line, = ax.plot([0], [0])  # empty line
linebuilder = LineBuilder(line)

plt.show()
```

works as expected for me.

Comment: is the only difference having used `self.cid` instead of `event.canvas.manager.key_press_handler_id` ?