# Matplotlib path contains_point

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've just discovered the matplotlib path functionality and I'm using it with `path.contains_point` to check whether points are found within a region defined by 2 bezier curves.

I'm getting some unexpected behaviour where `contains_point` is returning `True` when I would have expected it to return `False`. Specifically, if the point to be tested is to the left of the region then it seems to be incorrect. On the right is ok.

Defining my paths as a number of straight lines rather than curves seems to work as expected.

A failing test case is as follows:

```
import matplotlib 
import matplotlib.path as mplPath
import matplotlib.patches as patches

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab
import pandas as pd

print "MPL Version {}".format(matplotlib.__version__) #1.5.0
print "MPL NP Version {}".format(matplotlib.__version__numpy__) #1.6

path_data = [
    (mplPath.Path.MOVETO, (2, 10)),
    (mplPath.Path.CURVE4, (0, 100)),
    (mplPath.Path.CURVE4, (20, 100)),
    (mplPath.Path.CURVE4, (40, 150)),
    (mplPath.Path.MOVETO, (40, 150)),
    (mplPath.Path.CURVE4, (42, 45)),
    (mplPath.Path.CURVE4, (20, 30)),
    (mplPath.Path.CURVE4, (2, 10))
    ]

codes, verts = zip(*path_data)
path = mplPath.Path(verts, codes)
patch = patches.PathPatch(path, facecolor='r', alpha=0.5)

#Plot the patch and a some of the test points to visualise
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.add_patch(patch)
ax.set_xlim(0, 50)
ax.set_ylim(0, 200)

ax.scatter(1, 50)
ax.scatter(20, 120)
ax.scatter(20, 25)
print path.contains_point((1,50)) #This should be false but is actually true
print path.contains_point((20,120)) #This should be false but is actually true
print path.contains_point((20, 25)) #This should be false and it is

plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide. Python version is 2.7, Anaconda Distro on Linux Mint 17.3

Jim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an open path (extra moveto command). Once you comment it out, it works fine.

```
path_data = [
    (mplPath.Path.MOVETO, (2, 10)),
    (mplPath.Path.CURVE4, (0, 100)),
    (mplPath.Path.CURVE4, (20, 100)),
    (mplPath.Path.CURVE4, (40, 150)),
  #  (mplPath.Path.MOVETO, (40, 150)),
    (mplPath.Path.CURVE4, (42, 45)),
    (mplPath.Path.CURVE4, (20, 30)),
    (mplPath.Path.CURVE4, (2, 10))
    ]
```