# Understanding matplotlib event handling: what are event and mpl_connect?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wanted to make it possible to show values when pressing a dot in my scatterplot. The solution was found here: [Possible to make labels appear when hovering over a point in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/possible-to-make-labels-appear-when-hovering-over-a-point-in-matplotlib)

Solution:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
import numpy as npy
from numpy.random import rand


# picking on a scatter plot (matplotlib.collections.RegularPolyCollection)

x, y, c, s = rand(4, 100)
def onpick3(event):
    ind = event.ind
    print 'onpick3 scatter:', ind, npy.take(x, ind), npy.take(y, ind)

fig = figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
col = ax1.scatter(x, y, 100*s, c, picker=True)
#fig.savefig('pscoll.eps')
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick3)

show()
```

And it solved my problem. But I don't understand how, I've been googling around without any luck. I know how to plot with matplotlib, so that's not where my knowledge is lacking.

One thing I don't understand is the `onpick3(event)` function. What is this event parameter? Because the function itself is called upon further down without any given arguments: `fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`mpl_connect` connects a signal to a slot. The slot is in this case `onpick3`.
Note that the slot is not called, i.e. [the syntax](http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.FigureCanvasBase.mpl_connect) is

```
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick3)
```

and *not*

```
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', onpick3())
```

It will only be called once the signal is triggered (mouse clicked on canvas). At this point the underlying `event` is provided as an argument in the function call.

You'll see that once you try to define the slot without argument. This would cause an error like `onpick3 expects 0 arguments but got 1` or so.

You'll find details on the matplotlib [event handling](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) page. 
The `event` itself is an instance of [`matplotlib.backend_bases.PickEvent`](http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.PickEvent). The `.ind` attribute is not well documented, but that is mainly because not all artists actually register this attribute to the event.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the thorough explanation. Made things a bit clearer! But what about event.ind? is .ind an attribute of the received argument or something? And what does it represent?

Comment: Yes `ind` is an attribute of the `event` class. See updates answer.