# Python: Interactive plot, mouse showing value in the plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, plotly

I have produced the following plot using the following code

```
np.random.seed(1)
points = np.random.uniform(0,1, size = (1000,2)
values = np.random.uniform(-1,1, size = 1000)
plt.scatter(*points.T, c=values cmap = ListedColormap(sns.color_palette('coolwarm'))
```

[image]

Now, I would like to be able to hover the mouse over the points and see what value in `values` they correspond to. Obviously, I could simply use a `plt.colorbar()` as seen in the next image

[image: image2]

by using the following code

```
sp = plt.scatter(*points.T, c=values cmap = ListedColormap(sns.color_palette('coolwarm'))
plt.colorbar(sp)
plt.show()
```

However while you are looking at the plot, it is a bit harder to really get the values, and it would be way too messy to put labels on the points. Thus why I want to make the plot interactive. I had a look at [matplotlib event handling](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html) and at the library [plot.ly](https://plot.ly/feed/).

They both seem to say that the can indeed do it (for instance, look [here](http://www.randalolson.com/2014/06/28/how-to-make-beautiful-data-visualizations-in-python-with-matplotlib/)) but none seems to explain *how*!

Any ideas?

Comment: There are already a lot of similar questions on this topic. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637113/possible-to-make-labels-appear-when-hovering-over-a-point-in-matplotlib-in-stem), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42867400/python-show-image-upon-hovering-over-a-point), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/possible-to-make-labels-appear-when-hovering-over-a-point-in-matplotlib). It's really hard to help without knowing what you have tried already. Hence we can probably close this question as duplicate of any of those.

Comment: If you want to show what you have tried, and where the problem lies, one could reopen the question and help you with the actual problem.