# Labeling coordinates in scatter plot using matplotlib for clustering algorithm

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to render scatter plot for clustering against a dataset with multiple attributes. The plot below shows a scatter plot output against 2 such attributes:
[image]

Now I want to show other attributes as I mouse over those colored coordinates. What I am showing as X, Y axis are just 2 such attributes but there are other attributes which I want to show when I mouse over those colored circles.

Looking for some guidance from the experts here.

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried? In how far did other answers not help?

Comment: I understand I can use annotate but  it attaches label to all the points one shot and it would make it un-readable as I may have large number of coordinates on the plot . I want the annotation to appear only when I bring the mouse over the coordinates.

Comment: See especially [my new answer to the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47166787/4124317).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest , thank you for your answer. it really helped