# Widget and graph don't show up in Jupyter lab (they show up as text)

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-lab

I was trying to use %matplotlib widget to achieve interactivity in Jupiter Lab. But the output plot and widgets only showed up as texts.
How to make the actual plot and widgets show up?

```
%matplotlib widget
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
x = [1,2,3]
y = [4,5,6]
plt.plot(x,y)
```

Output:

```
Canvas(toolbar=Toolbar(toolitems=[('Home', 'Reset original view', 'home', 'home'), ('Back', 'Back to previous …
[1]:
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x114777b38>]
```

Comment: I believe you're missing `plt.show()`

Comment: No, it is not because of missing `plt.show()`. I have exactly the same problem, no figure, same text output! Ans also surprisingly since yesterday. I wonder if it is a problem with a new version of Jupyter Lab being released or something like that

Comment: @alyishere Has my answer solved your problem? If not leave a comment and I will try to help, if yes please accept as a solution

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. Apparently, there is an issue with the Jupyter Lab version and packages, see [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/pkgbase/python-ipympl/?O=0&PP=10) what other users with the same problem have written.

The things that enabled the visualization of the plots for me are:

1.) Make sure that you have Jupyter Lab version > 1.0 and ipywidgets > 7.5 installed, as adviced [here](http://github.com/matplotlib/jupyter-matplotlib/issues/133). Just type in a jupyter lab cell `!jupyter lab --version`, `!conda list ipywidgets` and check for yourself.

2.) Open Jupyter Lab from the terminal with the command `jupyter lab`. I was using before a programme that was making for me a short cut, so I don't have to open the terminal, but it was opening an older version of Jupyter Lab

Answer (score 3):

I know question is old, but google brought me here when I had exactly the same issue, and I eventually figured it out.

In my case, I had neglected to install @jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-manager.  Adding this via the lab extensions tab, rebuilding and reloading resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I missed!

Comment: Glad it helped! :) If you update to JupyterLab 3.*, see my answer here.  The process is much simpler! https://stackoverflow.com/a/66246240/10705616