# JupyterLab fig does not show. It shows blank result (but works fine on jupyternotebook)

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, candlestick-chart, alpha-vantage

I am new to JupyterLab trying to learn.

When I try to plot a graph, it works fine on jupyter notebook, but does not show the result on jupyterlab. Can anyone help me with this?

**Here are the codes below:**

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
import time
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import style
# from matplotlib.widgets import EllipseSelector
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries
```

**Here is the code for plotting below:**

```
def candlestick(df):
    fig = go.Figure(data = [go.Candlestick(x = df["Date"], open = df["Open"], high = df["High"], low = df["Low"], close = df["Close"])])
    fig.show()
```

**JupyterLab Result:**
[Link to the image (JupyterLab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1guHc.jpg)

**JupyterNotebook Result:**
[Link to the image (Jupyter Notebook)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr8q1.png)

I have updated both JupyterLab and Notebook to the latest version. I do not know what is causing JupyterLab to stop showing the figure.

Thank you for reading my post. Help would be greatly appreciated.

**Note***

*I did not include the parts for data reading (Stock OHLC values). It contains the API keys. I am sorry for inconvenience.
Also, this is my second post on stack overflow. If this is not a well-written post, I am sorry. I will try to put more effort if it is possible. Thank you again for help.*

Comment: You got the %inline magic declared for matplotlib?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

run the following and then restart your jupyter lab

```
jupyter labextension install @jupyterlab/plotly-extension
```

Start the lab with:

```
jupyter lab
```

Test with the following code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries

def candlestick(df):
    fig = go.Figure(data = [go.Candlestick(x = df.index, open = df["1. open"], high = df["2. high"], low = df["3. low"], close = df["4. close"])])
    fig.show()

# preferable to save your key as an environment variable....
key = # key here

ts = TimeSeries(key = key, output_format = "pandas")
data_av_hist, meta_data_av_hist = ts.get_daily('AAPL')

candlestick(data_av_hist)
```

> Note: Depending on system and installation of JupyterLab versus bare Jupyter, `jlab` may work instead of `jupyter`

**Longer explanation:**

Since this issue is with plotly and not matplotlib, you do NOT have to use the "inline magic" of:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

Each extension has to be installed to the jupyter lab, you can see the list with:

```
jupyter labextension list
```

For a more verbose explanation on another extension, please see related issue:
[jupyterlab interactive plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50149562/jupyterlab-interactive-plot)

Comment: Wow this works really well. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: Sorry, this did not work for me. Any other solutions to use?

Comment: @MANEESHMOHAN Install with jupyter labextension install plotlywidget in JupyterLab, otherwise just install Plotly.py and it will automatically work in Classic Notebooks. For more details - https://www.npmjs.com/package/jupyterlab-plotly

Comment: Depending on system and installation of JupyterLab versus bare Jupyter, "jlab" may work instead of "jupyter"

Answer (score 0):

[Patrick Collins already gave the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58418526/8284356).

However, the current JupyterLab might not be supported by the extension, and for various reasons one might not be able to update the JupyterLab:

> ValueError: The extension "@jupyterlab/plotly-extension" does not yet support the current version of JupyterLab.

In this condition a quick workaround would be to save the image and show it again:

```
from IPython.display import Image

fig.write_image("image.png")
Image(filename='image.png')
```

To get the `write_image()` method of Plotly to work, `kaleido` must be installed:

```
pip install -U kaleido
```

This is a full example (originally from [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/gantt/)) to test this workaround:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

from IPython.display import Image

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="Job A", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28', Resource="Alex"),
    dict(Task="Job B", Start='2009-03-05', Finish='2009-04-15', Resource="Alex"),
    dict(Task="Job C", Start='2009-02-20', Finish='2009-05-30', Resource="Max")
])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Resource", color="Resource")

if not os.path.exists("images"):
    os.mkdir("images")

fig.write_image("images/fig1.png")
Image(filename='images/fig1.png')
```