# interactive plot in notebook vs jupyterlab

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

With Jupyter Notebook 6.5.4, Python 3.8.13, IPython 8.12.0, I can make an interactive plot with:

```
from ipywidgets import interactive, FloatSlider
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook 
#inline doesn't work in jupyter notebook 
m_widget = FloatSlider(min=-2, max=2, step=.5, readout_format='.3f', continuous_update=False)
b_widget = FloatSlider(min=-5, max=5, step=.5, readout_format='.1e', continuous_update=False)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, num=1000)
l, = ax.plot(x, r_widget.value * x + c_widget.value)
ax.set_ylim(-5, 5)
def f(m, b):
    l.set_ydata(m*x+b) 
    fig.canvas.draw()
interactive_plot = interactive(f, m = m_widget, b=b_widget )
interactive_plot
```

and the interactive plot works with pan/zoom and updates as I slide the widgets.
I thought this technique would be better/faster/more efficient since I am not creating the figure with each slider adjustment, but instead only updating the line data. Also, I found if I didn't update the line data directly, I would end up with new lines on each update, instead of just changing the line.
I switched to jupyterlab 3.6.3, and a few others have asked about the differences with interactive plotting between jupyterlab and jupyter notebook, however those solutions are 3-4 years old and are not solving my issue.
In jupyterlab, I can only get `interactive` to work with `%matplotlib inline` and in the following style:

```
%matplotlib inline  
from ipywidgets import interactive
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
m_widget = FloatSlider(min=-2, max=2, step=.5, readout_format='.3f', continuous_update=False)
b_widget = FloatSlider(min=-5, max=5, step=.5, readout_format='.1e', continuous_update=False)
def f(m, b):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))
    x = np.linspace(-10, 10, num=1000)
    ax.plot(x, m * x + b)
    ax.set_ylim(-5, 5)
    plt.show()

interactive_plot = interactive(f, m=m_widget, b=b_widget)
interactive_plot
```

Using `%matplotib notebook` and `%matplotlib widget` both result in `Javascript Error: IPython is not defined`. If I move the `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))` above the function `f`, the plot does nothing.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55848505/7941309) has not changed the behavior I'm describing. I have `ipympl 0.9.3`.
Should I not expect my older style of making interactive plots to work? Is there even an advantage to that (besides being able to pan/zoom)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this [discussion](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/7715#issuecomment-659587274) and so I did `conda install nodejs` and now the first code block in my question works with `%matplotlib widget` and also `%matplotlib ipympl`, with both types of interaction (the widgets and the pan/zoom).

Answer (score 0):

In JupyterLab 3.4.8, the following variations of your second code block works to have both the pan/zoom, etc. 'interactivity' options and the ipywidgets interactivity of the plot.

```py
%matplotlib ipympl
from ipywidgets import interactive, FloatSlider
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
m_widget = FloatSlider(min=-2, max=2, step=.5, readout_format='.3f', continuous_update=False)
b_widget = FloatSlider(min=-5, max=5, step=.5, readout_format='.1e', continuous_update=False)
def f(m, b):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))
    x = np.linspace(-10, 10, num=1000)
    ax.plot(x, m * x + b)
    ax.set_ylim(-5, 5)
    plt.show()

interactive_plot = interactive(f, m=m_widget, b=b_widget)
interactive_plot
```

This is where `ipympl` is installed.

This also works:

```py
%matplotlib widget
from ipywidgets import interactive, FloatSlider
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
m_widget = FloatSlider(min=-2, max=2, step=.5, readout_format='.3f', continuous_update=False)
b_widget = FloatSlider(min=-5, max=5, step=.5, readout_format='.1e', continuous_update=False)
def f(m, b):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4))
    x = np.linspace(-10, 10, num=1000)
    ax.plot(x, m * x + b)
    ax.set_ylim(-5, 5)
    plt.show()

interactive_plot = interactive(f, m=m_widget, b=b_widget)
interactive_plot
```

This is because as explained 'Basic Example' section in the documentation for `ipympl` [here](https://matplotlib.org/ipympl/#basic-example):

> "To activate the ipympl backend all you need to do is include the `%matplotlib ipympl` magic in the notebook. Alternatively you can use `%matplotlib widget` which will have the same effect."

I can direct you to a place to compare what you see with what you should see. Click [here](https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/fomightez/communication_voila/master?urlpath=%2Flab%2Ftree%2Fnotebooks%2FDonut%20plot%20on%20a%20widget%20tab.ipynb) and after session starts up, open a new notebook and run your second code block. That is JupyterLab 3.4.8 (presently -- it will change over time because it isn't locked) with ipympl installed.

I have verified that the same two code blocks will also work in JupyterLab 4.0.3, too. You can demonstrate that for yourself by clicking [here](https://notebooks.gesis.org/binder/v2/gist/fomightez/e6f5ec9703c87aabd4b25d26b67e4e35/HEAD?urlpath=lab) to get a session with JupyterLab 4.0.3 with ipympl installed.
I'll note that to make a version of a MyBinder session that has `ipympl` installed properly, I had to add before build & launch as it is tricky install and doesn't work if installed later in a running session. **In fact, a situation similar to this is probably what you may be seeing because the result, giving javascript error, is similar to what you report.**

---

By the way, this 'interactive plot' is showing **two types of interactivity**. It exhibits both the interactive features of matplotlib ('ipympl-style interactivity') and ipywidget interactivity in controlling updating of the plot via floating slider widget controller. See an example of 'ipympl-style interactivity', in other words the interactive features of matplotlib, [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/ipympl#example) and see [here](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Using%20Interact.html) for a discussion with further examples of using ipywidget's `interact` and `interactive` to automatically creates user interface (UI) controls for exploring code and data interactively.

Comment: thanks so much. I will also have to look in detail later today.

Comment: That binder link gave me errors ending in a "no such image"

Comment: [This link](https://notebooks.gesis.org/binder/v2/gist/fomightez/e6f5ec9703c87aabd4b25d26b67e4e35/HEAD?urlpath=lab) just launched for me after some spinning. Depending on things, sometimes mybinder can be slow and patience is required.