# Can't capture Mouse and Click events from Jupyterlab 4.1.2 matplotlib interactive plot

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-lab, matplotlib-widget

I tried the Jupyter notebook example for Matplotlib Event Handling and seemed to get no results.

I downloaded the jupyter notebook from https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/coords_demo.html and attempted to run this code ([github source here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/bf6cc30c0282917d8da2befa1f9379083291d41a/galleries/examples/event_handling/coords_demo.py)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backend_bases import MouseButton

t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)


def on_move(event):
    if event.inaxes:
        print(f'data coords {event.xdata} {event.ydata},',
              f'pixel coords {event.x} {event.y}')


def on_click(event):
    if event.button is MouseButton.LEFT:
        print('disconnecting callback')
        plt.disconnect(binding_id)


binding_id = plt.connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)
plt.connect('button_press_event', on_click)

plt.show()
```

And all I got was a sine plot but no prints of data and pixel coordinates.  Here's a screen shot of my notebook after executing the cell, clicking and moving on the image for a while, and then hitting a shift-return or two to execute the next couple cells:

[image]

I expected to have move or click coordinates printed or collected somewhere, but I see nothing but the plain plot.

I also tried rerunning it with a `%matplotlib widget` decoration on the cell, which produced the interactive plot zooming widgets, but still didn't print coordinates.

I'm using Chrome on a Mac with:

```
% jupyter --version
Selected Jupyter core packages...
IPython          : 8.21.0
ipykernel        : 6.29.2
ipywidgets       : 8.1.2
jupyter_client   : 8.6.0
jupyter_core     : 5.7.1
jupyter_server   : 2.12.5
jupyterlab       : 4.1.2
nbclient         : 0.8.0
nbconvert        : 7.16.1
nbformat         : 5.9.2
notebook         : not installed
qtconsole        : not installed
traitlets        : 5.14.1
```

### With %matplotib ipympl

With this code:

```
%matplotlib ipympl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from matplotlib.backend_bases import MouseButton

t = np.arange(0.0, 1.0, 0.01)
s = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)


def on_move(event):
    if event.inaxes:
        print(f'data coords {event.xdata} {event.ydata},',
              f'pixel coords {event.x} {event.y}')


def on_click(event):
    if event.button is MouseButton.LEFT:
        print('disconnecting callback')
        plt.disconnect(binding_id)


binding_id = plt.connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)
plt.connect('button_press_event', on_click)

plt.show()
```

...and making sure ipympl is installed, restarting he browser, and restarting `jupyter lab` I have the same non-results:

After moving and clicking I still do not see the any movement coordinate or click data messages.  Should they show up in the cell? somewhere?

My results are as before:

[image]

```
% conda list |grep ipympl
ipympl                    0.9.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
```

Matplotlib issue on fixing the xample/doc raised at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/27837

Comment: You need to use `ipympl` in conjunction with JupyterLab 4 for interactive plotting with matplotlib.  Depending on how you installed Python Jupyter, you'd first use `%conda install -c conda-forge ipympl` or `%pip install ipympl` in a new cell in the notebook where you want to use them to install. Then restart the kernel and **refresh your browser** to propagate the many changes `ipympl` needs. In fact it is best to restart your browser and Jupyter entirely after this as impympl is quite complex. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76860834/8508004) for some more guidance and ...

Comment: <continued> a place where you can launch a temporary Jupyter session on a remote machine  without logging in to try and compare to what you are encountering. That session I suggest will already have `ipympl` installed to make it easier to test. I forgot to mention that after installing, you'd use `%matplotlib ipympl` near the start of your notebook or at the top of the cell with the plot. You don't want to have any other `%matplotlib` commands run in the session first for this all to work.

Comment: [This thread](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/interactive-matplotlib-in-jupyterlab-no-longer-working/20017/3?u=fomightez) might also help you navigate using interactive plotting with matplotlib in the current Juptyer landscape.

Comment: Thanks @Wayne.  I had ipympl installed before, but I went through and re-started and refreshed things, and still had mouse movement/click data results.   I've tried iterations with and without %matplotlib widget and %matplotlib ipympl

Comment: Oh I was responding before I actually say code and thought you were referring to typical interactive use. So at least the coordinates will display just fine at least. Just in the code block you share now under 'With %matplotib ipympl', don't include any of the code after `ax.plot(t, s)`. That will be the last line. You'll see the coordinates below at least. As for capturing them, let me look further. I thought I helped someone troubleshoot this code, or a something very similar approach, recently.

Comment: So looking into this now with [the source of that code](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/event_handling/coords_demo.html), I think it may need a different backend. I think that is made to work with tkinter or Qt, see [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/22681#issuecomment-1074675177) where `MouseEvent` discussed.  In short, this isn't really compatible with typical Jupyter these days. You'd use ipywidgets to do interactive stuff with matplotlib like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77128516/8508004). I think. I know it shows a notebook but I wonder if that is just...

Comment: <continued> an automated process that makes those with the code in them? I'm stumped for now. But maybe you can install tkinter  and the python version will at least work for you? And then you can try use `tkAgg`. I'll try to ponder it more but I'm baffled as to the trick needed here for now. UPDATE: I do see if you go to [Matplotlib's 'Interactive figures' documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/figure/interactive.html), it says "Matplotlib ships with backends binding to several GUI toolkits (Qt, Tk, Wx, GTK, macOS, JavaScript) and ...

Comment: <continued> third party packages provide bindings to kivy and Jupyter Lab." And then below it is using `QtAgg` which is a different backend then Jupyter. And then below there under 'Jupyter Notebooks / JupyterLab' it says to use `ipymple` like we've been trying. I'm stumped for now.

Comment: From the outside it is very confusing. "Interactive" can mean so many different things.  The code I'm ultimately trying to understand for works looks like it adds an icon on that interactive bar, and then uses that mode to capture and classify points near the clicked location.  If this sample code worked, I think the other code might make more sense. /// Can you use multiple backends in a jupyterlab document?

Comment: I changed the title to reflect I that I'm interested in the mouse click/movement events in the demo & how to implement them in jupyter.

Comment: Good. I'm stumped about this one. Hopefully someone else sees the modified title.