# Scaling issue on a barchart

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, graph

I'm trying to plot some data on the same chart. I'm having issue with the scaling on the bar portion of the chart. The largest bar on the chart seems to only go up to ab out -60k. I know the max on the data is closer to -166k. Im not sure what I'm doing wrong with the bar data. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

I also noticed that when I make the chart window larger, the larger bars start to creep higher and not staying to scale.

[image]

This is the code I have:
fig,ax = plt.subplots()

```
ax.bar(stats_df.index, stats_df['MaxDrawPerPeriod'])
axtwin = ax.twinx()
axtwin.plot(stats_df.index, stats_df['ClosedPL_Accum'])
ax.set_ylim(0,-160000)
# axtwin.set_ylim()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Oh, you're plotting over seven years. Each bar is one day wide; however on a 600 pixel graphics one day corresponds only to 0.2 pixels. Hence the probability that a bar is actually displayed is 20%. You can probably set a `linewidth=0.72` and/or `edgecolor="C0"` to your `bar` plot. Or you make sure the bars are actually at least, say 10 days wide, `width=10`.

Comment: that did the trick. Thank you for all the help tonight. It's greatly appreciated