# Printing names of graphs by hovering on them

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, hover

I have 3 text files with specific names that I want to plot in a single figure. Here are my files:

111.txt

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

222.txt

```
0 0
1 3
2 6
3 9
```

333.txt

```
0 0
1 5
2 10
3 15
```

I want the names of the graphs (without '**.txt**') to apprear next to the mouse cursor when I move the mouse cursor on these lines. This is what I have tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

def GetFiles():
    return [file for file in os.listdir('/home/myfolder') if 
file.endswith(".txt")]

#Get All Available file in current directry
textfiles=GetFiles()

#Storing the names of the files without .txt in an array
s=[]
for j in range (len(textfiles)):
    without_txt = textfiles[j].replace(".txt", "")
    s.append(without_txt)
#print (s)

fig = plt.figure()
plot = fig.add_subplot(111)

# plot the text files in the folder
for i in range(len(s)):
    plt.plotfile(str(textfiles[i]), delimiter=' ', cols=(0, 1), 
linestyle='-', linewidth=2, color='b', newfig=False,gid=s[i])

#plt.gca().invert_xaxis()

def on_plot_hover(event):
    for curve in plot.get_lines():
        if curve.contains(event)[0]:
            print "over %s" % curve.get_gid()  

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_plot_hover)
plt.show()
```

I followed the second solution mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/possible-to-make-labels-appear-when-hovering-over-a-point-in-matplotlib) post. It prints the name of the graph but as I said I **want it to appear next to the mouse cursor while hovering**. I could not figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The linked solution creates an `Annotation` via `plt.annotate`. You're completely missing that part in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't use the annotation from your example link. Just adding this to your code and setting the annotation's `xy` value to the `xdata` and `ydata` values of your hover event gets you what you are looking for:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os

def GetFiles():
    return [file for file in os.listdir('/home/myfolder') if 
file.endswith(".txt")]

#Get All Available file in current directry
textfiles=GetFiles()

#Storing the names of the files without .txt in an array
s=[]
for j in range (len(textfiles)):
    without_txt = textfiles[j].replace(".txt", "")
    s.append(without_txt)

fig = plt.figure()
plot = fig.add_subplot(111)

annot = plot.annotate("", xy=(2,2), xytext=(10,10),textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"))
annot.set_visible(False)

# plot the text files in the folder
for i in range(len(s)):
    plt.plotfile(str(textfiles[i]), delimiter=' ', cols=(0, 1), 
linestyle='-', linewidth=2, color='b', newfig=False,gid=s[i])

def update_annot(x,y, text):
    annot.set_text(text)
    annot.xy = [x,y]

def on_plot_hover(event):
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    for curve in plot.get_lines():
        if curve.contains(event)[0]:
            print("over %s" % curve.get_gid())
            update_annot(event.xdata, event.ydata, curve.get_gid())
            annot.set_visible(True)
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        else:
            if vis:
                annot.set_visible(False)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_plot_hover)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Leo, as a side note, as I learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54403514/10944175) you should look into plotting using something different from `plotfile`: "once you want to make significant changes to figure or axes, best do not rely on `plotfile`"