# Matplotlib annotation text expanding outside axes

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have a scatterplot with multiple points, sometimes overlapping, so there is a hover box annotation on each point (used the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47166787/3220769) to create this). To deal with the multiple points and sometimes long descriptions, there is a line break in the annotation. The problem is with multiple lines, the annotation box builds up instead of down making it go outside the axis like seen below. Is there a way to have the text start at the line right below the axis then build down into the plot?

Relevant code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

x = np.random.rand(15)
y = np.random.rand(15)
names = np.array(list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO"))
c = np.random.randint(1,5,size=15)

norm = plt.Normalize(1,4)
cmap = plt.cm.RdYlGn

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
sc = plt.scatter(x,y,c=c, s=100, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0.05, 0.95), xycoords='axes fraction',
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                    zorder=1000)
annot.set_visible(False)

def update_annot(ind):

    pos = sc.get_offsets()[ind["ind"][0]]
    annot.xy = pos
    text = "{}".format("\n".join([f"{n}: {names[n]}" for n in ind["ind"]]))
    annot.set_text(text)
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_facecolor(cmap(norm(c[ind["ind"][0]])))
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(0.4)


def hover(event):
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        cont, ind = sc.contains(event)
        if cont:
            update_annot(ind)
            annot.set_visible(True)
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        else:
            if vis:
                annot.set_visible(False)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)

plt.show()
```

How it looks with one line text in annotation

[image]

How it looks with two line text in annotation (hover point overlaps two points). Would ideally have the `0: A` where `8: I` is, then `8: I` below it

[image]

Comment: have you tried changing the pos = sc.get_offsets()[ind["ind"][0]]
    annot.xy = pos, to an inverse ?

Comment: I guess a workaround is using `xy=(0.05, 0.05)` in the annotation, to put it at the bottom left and have it build up into the plot

Comment: kind of a hacky way yes that could work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the code is a bit overkill to ask the simple question how to align a text or annotation.

That is done via the `verticalalignment` or `va` argument (or the `horizontalalignment` / `ha`). Set it to `"top"` to align the text from the top.

Use the `xytext` and `textcoords` arguments (just as in the linked code) to give the text some offset in units of points (i.e. independent on how large the figure is).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

annot = ax.annotate("Three\nLine\nText", xy=(0, 1), xycoords='axes fraction',
                    xytext=(5,-5), textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"), va="top")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of the `verticalalignment` argument but that does exactly it.