# Annotate lines of a plot with matplotlib when hover with mouse

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, hover

I want to annotate different lines on a plot when hovering with the mouse, the same way is done here with points [Possible to make labels appear when hovering over a point in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/possible-to-make-labels-appear-when-hovering-over-a-point-in-matplotlib)

I tried to adapt this code as the following :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)
y = np.random.rand(4,15)
x = [np.arange(15) for i in range(len(y))]
names = np.array(list("ABCD"))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lines = []
for i in range(len(names)):
    lines.append(ax.plot(x[i],y[i]))

annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0,0), xytext=(20,20),textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
annot.set_visible(False)

def update_annot(ind):
    pos = line.get_offsets()[ind["ind"][0]]
    annot.xy = pos
    text = "{}, {}".format(" ".join(list(map(str,ind["ind"]))), 
                           " ".join([names[n] for n in ind["ind"]]))
    annot.set_text(text)
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_facecolor(cmap(norm(c[ind["ind"][0]])))
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(0.4)

def hover(event):
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        for line in lines:
            cont, ind = line.contains(event)
            if cont:
                update_annot(ind)
                annot.set_visible(True)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()
            else:
                if vis:
                    annot.set_visible(False)
                    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)
plt.show()
```

The problem is when I hover the mouse on the plot I have the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: I marked as duplicate, because that question contains two different ways of producing hovers for lines.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot blindly copy the code used for `scatter()` and use it for `plot()`as the returned artists are completly different.

In addition, and the root cause for the error you are seeing is that `plot()` returns a list of artists (even when plotting a single line). I've modified you code to give something that should be close to what you wanted like so:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
y = np.random.rand(4, 15)
x = [np.arange(15) for i in range(len(y))]
names = np.array(list("ABCD"))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lines = []
for i in range(len(names)):
    l, = ax.plot(x[i], y[i], label=names[i])
    lines.append(l)

annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0, 0), xytext=(20, 20), textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
annot.set_visible(False)


def update_annot(line, idx):
    posx, posy = [line.get_xdata()[idx], line.get_ydata()[idx]]
    annot.xy = (posx, posy)
    text = f'{line.get_label()}: {posx:.2f}-{posy:.2f}'
    annot.set_text(text)
    # annot.get_bbox_patch().set_facecolor(cmap(norm(c[ind["ind"][0]])))
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(0.4)


def hover(event):
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        for line in lines:
            cont, ind = line.contains(event)
            if cont:
                update_annot(line, ind['ind'][0])
                annot.set_visible(True)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()
            else:
                if vis:
                    annot.set_visible(False)
                    fig.canvas.draw_idle()


fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)
plt.show()
```