# Making labels appear while hovering over plot for graphs *with high y-axis values*, multiple lines and multiple axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, hover, annotate

I wanted to read values off of the graphs that I made using python similar to how the data point values show up in an excel plot when you hover over a data point. Using various solutions here, I wrote up the below code to label the points as I hovered over them.

However, I can't seem to label some points when there are high y-axis values (that's my assumption on why it doesn't work), nor can I get the box to have a solid background so I can read the coordinates clearly (tried setting alpha to 1 but didn't work).[Here's a picture of how one such point shows up far away from the actual location and with the text blocked by the curves behind it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhGon.png) Oddly enough, when all the y-axis values are below 1, the code worked fine.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

x_data = list(range(0,30))
y1_data_a = np.sort(np.random.rand(30))
y1_data_b = np.sort(np.random.rand(30))
y1_data_c = [0.4 for point in x_data]
y2_data_a = [point**2 for point in x_data]
y2_data_b = [point*0.5 for point in y2_data_a]
y3_data = [(10/(point+1)) for point in x_data]

# #The code works fine with this data
# x_data = list(range(0,30))
# y1_data_a = np.sort(np.random.rand(30))
# y1_data_b = np.sort(np.random.rand(30))
# y1_data_c = [0.4 for point in x_data]
# y2_data_a = np.random.rand(30)
# y2_data_b = np.sort(np.random.rand(30))
# y3_data = np.sort(np.random.rand(30))[::-1]

fig, y1_axis = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

y2_axis = y1_axis.twinx()
y3_axis = y1_axis.twinx()

def make_patch_spines_invisible(ax):
    ax.set_frame_on(True)
    ax.patch.set_visible(False)
    for sp in ax.spines.values():
        sp.set_visible(False)

y3_axis.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", 1.2))
make_patch_spines_invisible(y3_axis)
y3_axis.spines["right"].set_visible(True)

plot1, = y1_axis.plot(x_data, y1_data_a, color="#000CFF", label="Temp1 (°C)")
plot2, = y1_axis.plot(x_data, y1_data_b, color="#FF5100", label="Temp2 (°C)")
plot3, = y1_axis.plot(x_data, y1_data_c, "r--", label="Critical Temp (°C)")

plot4, = y2_axis.plot(x_data, y2_data_a, color="#000000", label="Pressure1 (atm)")
plot5, = y2_axis.plot(x_data, y2_data_b, color="#17E111", label="Pressure2 (atm)")

plot6, = y3_axis.plot(x_data, y3_data, color="#D418DE", label="Volume (m3)")

y1_axis.set_xlabel("Time (hrs)")
y1_axis.set_ylabel("Temperature (°C)")
y2_axis.set_ylabel("Pressure (atm)")
y3_axis.set_ylabel("Volume (m3)")

y3_axis.yaxis.label.set_color(plot6.get_color())

tkw = dict(size=4, width=1.5)
y1_axis.tick_params(axis='y', **tkw)
y2_axis.tick_params(axis='y', **tkw)
y3_axis.tick_params(axis='y', colors=plot6.get_color(), **tkw)
y1_axis.tick_params(axis='x', **tkw)

lines = [plot1, plot2, plot4, plot5, plot6]

plt.title("Labeling data points for plots with Multiple Axes and Lines", fontdict=None, loc='center')

annot = y1_axis.annotate("", xy=(0, 0), xytext=(20, 20), textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", facecolor="#FFFFFF"),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
annot.set_visible(False)


def update_annot(line, annot, ind):
    posx, posy = [line.get_xdata()[ind], line.get_ydata()[ind]]
    annot.xy = (posx, posy)
    text = f'{line.get_label()}: ({posx:.2f},{posy:.2f})'
    annot.set_text(text)
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(1)


def hover(event):
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes in [y1_axis, y2_axis, y3_axis]:
        for line in lines:
            cont, ind = line.contains(event)
            if cont:
                update_annot(line, annot, ind['ind'][0])
                annot.set_visible(True)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()
            else:
                if vis:
                    annot.set_visible(False)
                    fig.canvas.draw_idle()


fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)
plt.show()
```

[The ticker on the bottom right of the plot only seems to show the values based on the last axis that has been used.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWHiQ.png) After searching here, I found 3 solutions that helps display a box containing the coordinates of a point:

1. [Possible to make labels appear when hovering over a point in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/possible-to-make-labels-appear-when-hovering-over-a-point-in-matplotlib) (Didn't use this code exactly since it's for scatter plots but found other solutions from here)
2. [Annotate lines of a plot with matplotlib when hover with mouse [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58056006/annotate-lines-of-a-plot-with-matplotlib-when-hover-with-mouse) (Used this to apply the previous solution to lines/curves)
3. [How to make labels appear when hovering over a point in multiple axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55891285/how-to-make-labels-appear-when-hovering-over-a-point-in-multiple-axis) (Used this to apply the labels to graphs with multiple axes)

How do I get the box to appear in graphs with high y-axis values and how do I make the box appear over the graphs so it can be read clearly? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, your problem is that you created your annotation as belonging to the axes `y1_axis`. When you were hovering over a point, you were setting the position of the annotation in the data coordinate of `y1_axis`, regardless of whether the line was in that axes or another.

The solution is to update not only the coordinates of the annotation, but also its `transform` to correctly map the point to the correct coordinates in pixels.

The same is true for the background of the annotation. Since you were creating it on the bottom-most axes, the annotation was above the line in these axes, but below the lines in the other axes. The solution here is to create the annotation in the top-most axes.

```py
(...)
# annotation should be on the top axis to avoid zorder problems
annot = fig.axes[-1].annotate("", xy=(0, 0), xytext=(20, 20), textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", facecolor="#FFFFFF"),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
annot.set_visible(False)

(...)
def update_annot(line, annot, ind):
    posx, posy = [line.get_xdata()[ind], line.get_ydata()[ind]]
    annot.xycoords = line.axes.transData  # set the correct transform for that line
    annot.xy = (posx, posy)
    text = f'{line.get_label()}: ({posx:.2f},{posy:.2f})'
    annot.set_text(text)
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(1)
(...)
```

Full code:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

x_data = list(range(0,30))
y1_data_a = np.sort(np.random.rand(30))
y1_data_b = np.sort(np.random.rand(30))
y1_data_c = [0.4 for point in x_data]
y2_data_a = [point**2 for point in x_data]
y2_data_b = [point*0.5 for point in y2_data_a]
y3_data = [(10/(point+1)) for point in x_data]

# #The code works fine with this data
# x_data = list(range(0,30))
# y1_data_a = np.sort(np.random.rand(30))
# y1_data_b = np.sort(np.random.rand(30))
# y1_data_c = [0.4 for point in x_data]
# y2_data_a = np.random.rand(30)
# y2_data_b = np.sort(np.random.rand(30))
# y3_data = np.sort(np.random.rand(30))[::-1]

fig, y1_axis = plt.subplots()
fig.subplots_adjust(right=0.75)

y2_axis = y1_axis.twinx()
y3_axis = y1_axis.twinx()

def make_patch_spines_invisible(ax):
    ax.set_frame_on(True)
    ax.patch.set_visible(False)
    for sp in ax.spines.values():
        sp.set_visible(False)

y3_axis.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", 1.2))
make_patch_spines_invisible(y3_axis)
y3_axis.spines["right"].set_visible(True)

plot1, = y1_axis.plot(x_data, y1_data_a, color="#000CFF", label="Temp1 (°C)")
plot2, = y1_axis.plot(x_data, y1_data_b, color="#FF5100", label="Temp2 (°C)")
plot3, = y1_axis.plot(x_data, y1_data_c, "r--", label="Critical Temp (°C)")

plot4, = y2_axis.plot(x_data, y2_data_a, color="#000000", label="Pressure1 (atm)")
plot5, = y2_axis.plot(x_data, y2_data_b, color="#17E111", label="Pressure2 (atm)")

plot6, = y3_axis.plot(x_data, y3_data, color="#D418DE", label="Volume (m3)")

y1_axis.set_xlabel("Time (hrs)")
y1_axis.set_ylabel("Temperature (°C)")
y2_axis.set_ylabel("Pressure (atm)")
y3_axis.set_ylabel("Volume (m3)")

y3_axis.yaxis.label.set_color(plot6.get_color())

tkw = dict(size=4, width=1.5)
y1_axis.tick_params(axis='y', **tkw)
y2_axis.tick_params(axis='y', **tkw)
y3_axis.tick_params(axis='y', colors=plot6.get_color(), **tkw)
y1_axis.tick_params(axis='x', **tkw)

lines = [plot1, plot2, plot4, plot5, plot6]

plt.title("Labeling data points for plots with Multiple Axes and Lines", fontdict=None, loc='center')

# annotation should be on the top axis to avoid zorder problems
annot = fig.axes[-1].annotate("", xy=(0, 0), xytext=(20, 20), textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", facecolor="#FFFFFF"),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
annot.set_visible(False)


def update_annot(line, annot, ind):
    posx, posy = [line.get_xdata()[ind], line.get_ydata()[ind]]
    annot.xycoords = line.axes.transData
    annot.xy = (posx, posy)
    text = f'{line.get_label()}: ({posx:.2f},{posy:.2f})'
    annot.set_text(text)
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(1)


def hover(event):
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes in [y1_axis, y2_axis, y3_axis]:
        for line in lines:
            cont, ind = line.contains(event)
            if cont:
                update_annot(line, annot, ind['ind'][0])
                annot.set_visible(True)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()
            else:
                if vis:
                    annot.set_visible(False)
                    fig.canvas.draw_idle()


fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)
plt.show()
```

Comment: wonderful answer but how can i change if X axis is not numbers its datetime having this issue in  text = f'{line.get_label()}: ({posx:.2f},{posy:.2f})' thank you