# adding tooltip for nodes in python networkx graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, tooltip, networkx

I created a directed graph using `networkx.DiGraph` then plotted it using `networkx.draw_spring(graph)`, so all the nodes of the graph have some details stored in a list of dictionaries.

How to add something like a "tooltip" to view these details on mouse hover on each node? If this is possible, how to make this "tooltip" always visible for all nodes, not just by hovering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Always visible

To label all the nodes, you just need to use `annotate`. Something like this

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.path_graph(5)
attrs = {0: {'attr1': 20, 'attr2': 'nothing'}, 1: {'attr2': 3}, 2: {'attr1': 42}, 3: {'attr3': 'hello'}, 4: {'attr1': 54, 'attr3': '33'}}
nx.set_node_attributes(G, attrs)
nx.draw(G)

for node in G.nodes:
    xy = pos[node]
    annot.xy = xy
    node_attr = G.nodes[node]
    text = '\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in G.nodes[node].items())
    text = f'node {node}\n' + text
    ax.annotate(text, xy=xy)
```

---

### On hover

Here's a working example of getting tooltip on hover. This is based off tooltips using standard matplotlib plots [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/possible-to-make-labels-appear-when-hovering-over-a-point-in-matplotlib). I used `draw_networkx_nodes` to get the objects used for hovering and displaying tooltips instead of using `draw_spring`. But you can manually define the position with `spring_layout`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.path_graph(5)
attrs = {0: {'attr1': 20, 'attr2': 'nothing'}, 1: {'attr2': 3}, 2: {'attr1': 42}, 3: {'attr3': 'hello'}, 4: {'attr1': 54, 'attr3': '33'}}
nx.set_node_attributes(G, attrs)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos, ax=ax)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, ax=ax)

annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0,0), xytext=(20,20),textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
annot.set_visible(False)

def update_annot(ind):
    node = ind["ind"][0]
    xy = pos[node]
    annot.xy = xy
    node_attr = {'node': node}
    node_attr.update(G.nodes[node])
    text = '\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in node_attr.items())
    annot.set_text(text)

def hover(event):
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        cont, ind = nodes.contains(event)
        if cont:
            update_annot(ind)
            annot.set_visible(True)
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        else:
            if vis:
                annot.set_visible(False)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's very specific, very awesome and very working :D , thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

FYI @busybear @ sudofix

This only works if you have your nodes starting from 0.

if you do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

nodes = list(range(5))

edges = []
for e1,e2 in zip(nodes[:-1],nodes[1:]):
    edges.append((e1,e2))

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from(nodes)
G.add_edges_from(edges)

attrs = {}
for node in G.nodes:
    attrs[node] = {'attr1': node, 'attr2': 'hello', 'attr3': 33}
```

and leave the rest as

```
nx.set_node_attributes(G, attrs)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos, ax=ax)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, ax=ax)

annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0,0), xytext=(20,20),textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
annot.set_visible(False)

def update_annot(ind):
    node = ind["ind"][0]
    xy = pos[node]
    annot.xy = xy
    node_attr = {'node': node}
    node_attr.update(G.nodes[node])
    text = '\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in node_attr.items())
    annot.set_text(text)

def hover(event):
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        cont, ind = nodes.contains(event)
        if cont:
            update_annot(ind)
            annot.set_visible(True)
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        else:
            if vis:
                annot.set_visible(False)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)

plt.show()
```

everything works great.

But if you change
`nodes = list(range(5))`
to be
`nodes = list(range(1,6))`
it does not work, because `node = ind["ind"][0]` returns the position of the nodes in `G.nodes` and not the name of the node, so accessing `pos[node]` and `G.nodes[node]` gets the wrong position (it is shifted by 1).

The solution is to create a mapping like

```
idx_to_node_dict = {}
for idx, node in enumerate(G.nodes):
    idx_to_node_dict[idx] = node
```

and fix the function to use it as:

```
def update_annot(ind):
    node_idx = ind["ind"][0]
    node = idx_to_node_dict[node_idx]
```