# Add a tooltip for graph edges using networkx and matplotlib (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I plotted a network graph in matplotlib and would like to have a tooltip that displays information when I hover the mouse over edges.

There is a solution for generating a tooltip when hovering over nodes ([adding tooltip for nodes in python networkx graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61604636/adding-tooltip-for-nodes-in-python-networkx-graph)). Can this be adapted for hovering over edges?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.path_graph(5)
attrs = {0: {'attr1': 20, 'attr2': 'nothing'}, 1: {'attr2': 3}, 2: {'attr1': 42}, 3: {'attr3': 'hello'}, 4: {'attr1': 54, 'attr3': '33'}}
nx.set_node_attributes(G, attrs)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nodes = nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos, ax=ax)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, ax=ax)

annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0,0), xytext=(20,20),textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
annot.set_visible(False)

def update_annot(ind):
    node = ind["ind"][0]
    xy = pos[node]
    annot.xy = xy
    node_attr = {'node': node}
    node_attr.update(G.nodes[node])
    text = '\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in node_attr.items())
    annot.set_text(text)

def hover(event):
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        cont, ind = nodes.contains(event)
        if cont:
            update_annot(ind)
            annot.set_visible(True)
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        else:
            if vis:
                annot.set_visible(False)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this example can be adapted fairly easily to work for edges instead of nodes.

First, let's apply the attributes to the edges rather than the nodes,:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

G = nx.path_graph(5)
attrs = {(0, 1): {'attr1': 20, 'attr2': 'nothing'}, 
         (1, 2): {'attr2': 3}, 
         (2, 3): {'attr1': 42}, 
         (3, 4): {'attr3': 'hello'}, 
         (4, 5): {'attr1': 54, 'attr3': '33'}}
nx.set_edge_attributes(G, attrs)
```

Now, we want to record the locations of the edges when we plot the figure, not the nodes:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos, ax=ax)
edges = nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos, ax=ax)

annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0,0), xytext=(20,20),textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
annot.set_visible(False)
```

Now, we just need to alter the `update_annot` and `hover` functions to look at the edges of the graph rather than the nodes. Because `pos` only holds the locations of the nodes, we find the average of the location of the nodes at either end of the edge in order to find the edge's midpoint.

```
def update_annot(ind):
    edge = list(G.edges)[ind["ind"][0]]
    xy = (pos[edge[0]] + pos[edge[1]])/2
    annot.xy = xy
    node_attr = {'edge': edge}
    node_attr.update(G.edges[edge])
    text = '\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in node_attr.items())
    annot.set_text(text)

def hover(event):
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        cont, ind = edges.contains(event)
        if cont:
            update_annot(ind)
            annot.set_visible(True)
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        else:
            if vis:
                annot.set_visible(False)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)

plt.show()
```

### Result

[image]