# Pyplot: Display label values when mouse hover point

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I have a very basic plot, for which I would like to add the ability to display values when mouse hovers over data points on the plot.

The code I use to create my line graph is as follows:

```
df_all['count'] = pd.to_numeric(df_all['count'])
cumulative = df_all['count'].cumsum()
cumulative.plot()

plt.plot()

print(plt.show())
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Additional answers for hover annotations: [How to add hovering annotations in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7908636/7758804)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further to the comment regarding [Plotly](https://plotly.com/python/), here is a *very* simple example of how to plot a graph, with hoverable trends.

Example code:

```
import random
import pandas as pd
from plotly.offline import plot

# Create a random list of values.
vals = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(100)]

# Create a test DataFrame.
df = pd.DataFrame({'count': vals})
df['cumsum'] = df['count'].cumsum()
```

Create the graph using Plotly:

```
# Plot the results.
traces = []
traces.append({'y': df['count'], 'name': 'Single Counts'})
traces.append({'y': df['cumsum'], 'name': 'Cumulative'})

plot({'data': traces})
```

Output:
As you can see, my cursor was hovering at x: 50, y: 248. The displayed text is highly configurable, as can be reviewed in the [hovertext documentation](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/).

[image]

TL;DR:
Given the extensive configuration capability Plotly provides, it's very easy to get lost in Dash, Plotly Express, Figure Factories, etc., and come to a conclusion of 'What solution do I really need?' - I thought it would be helpful to show a very stripped down (yet entirely functional) example of how to plot a graph with hoverable trends.

Comment: This was exactly what the Doctor ordered!!! I was having intermittent success displaying a plotly.express version but using plotly.offline seems to display without fail. Brilliant!

Comment: Excellent, my pleasure.  Really glad it’s working for you!