# How to add data label when mouse hover a line chart? (Matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know this question has been asked before but I couldn't find the answer to my question so I hope to find a solution here
I want to create the chart to show First day of snow vs. Last day of snow. The chart is the following:

[image]

the X axis is the year, Y axis is the day in the year that has snow. However, I want to the data label when mouse hover to show the actual date.
Example: [x,y] = [140, 1873]. Data label to be '1873-11-18'.
The data label comes from different column of the data frame.
Here is my dataframe:

[image]

```
fig, ((ax1,ax2)) = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(12,8),constrained_layout=True)
colors = ['skyblue', 'coral', 'mediumaquamarine']
Xticks = np.arange(1880, 2021, 20)
snow.plot(x = 'Snow Year', y = ['First DOS', 'Last DOS'], color = colors, ax = ax1)
snow.plot(x = 'Snow Year', y = ['Snow length'], color = 'mediumaquamarine', ax = ax2)
sns.regplot(x='Snow Year',y='First DOS', data = snow, fit_reg=True, ax = ax1) 
sns.regplot(x='Snow Year',y='Last DOS', data = snow, fit_reg=True, ax = ax1) 
sns.regplot(x='Snow Year',y='Snow length', data = snow, fit_reg=True, ax = ax2)
ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1,1), loc="upper left")
ax2.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1,1), loc="upper left")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add hovering annotations in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/how-to-add-hovering-annotations-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/) library to automatically add an annotation while hovering. The annotation function can adapt the text to be displayed, for example by looking up rows in the dataframe. Newlines (`'\n'`) can distribute the text over multiple lines.

Here is an example for the first plot. The code can easily be adapted to display additional columns from the dataframe.

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import randint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplcursors
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

def show_annation1(sel):
    index = round(sel.target.index)
    snow.iloc[index]['First Snow Date']
    row = snow.iloc[index]
    sel.annotation.set_text(f"{row['First Snow Date']} - {row['Last Snow Date']}\n(Length: {row['Snow length']})")

# create some dummy data for testing purposes
years = np.arange(1870, 2021)
snow = pd.DataFrame({'Snow Year': years,
                     'First Snow Date': [f'{y - 1}-{randint(11, 13)}-{randint(1, 31)}' for y in years],
                     'First DOS': randint(135, 200, len(years)),
                     'Last Snow Date': [f'{y}-{randint(3, 5)}-{randint(1, 31)}' for y in years],
                     'Last DOS': np.random.randint(250, 304, len(years))})
snow['Snow length'] = snow['Last DOS'] - snow['First DOS']
fig, ((ax1, ax2)) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(12, 8))
colors = ['skyblue', 'coral', 'mediumaquamarine']
ax2.set_xticks = np.arange(1880, 2021, 20)
snow.plot(x='Snow Year', y=['First DOS', 'Last DOS'], color=colors, ax=ax1)
snow.plot(x='Snow Year', y=['Snow length'], color='mediumaquamarine', ax=ax2)
sns.regplot(x='Snow Year', y='First DOS', data=snow, fit_reg=True, ax=ax1)
sns.regplot(x='Snow Year', y='Last DOS', data=snow, fit_reg=True, ax=ax1)
sns.regplot(x='Snow Year', y='Snow length', data=snow, fit_reg=True, ax=ax2)
ax1.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc="upper left")
ax2.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc="upper left")

cursor1 = mplcursors.cursor(ax1.lines, hover=True)
cursor1.connect('add', show_annation1)
# cursor2 = mplcursors.cursor(ax2.lines, hover=True)
# cursor2.connect('add', show_annation2)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: using mplcursors to display a custom annotation]