# How to add hovering annotations with multiple curves

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplcursors

I am using matplotlib to plot multiple curves (time series) in one plot. To do this, I use a `for` loop as seen below.

```py
%matplotlib

for i in range(0, len(force)):

    plt.plot(distance, (force[i]), alpha=0.1)
    
    plt.xlabel('Distance [mm]', fontsize=12)
    plt.ylabel('Force [N]', fontsize=12)
```

Unfortunately, with the number of curves (approx. 70) that I have, the plot would be unreadable if I labeled each curve. Does anyone know of a way to create labels that only appear when the cursor hovers in the vicinity of that curve (timeseries)?

I looked on the example from this post, but have no clue how to adapt it to my issue:

[Possible to make labels appear when hovering over a point in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/how-to-add-hovering-annotations-in-matplotlib)

Comment: can you provide standalone code for debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/).  Each curve can have a unique label, which is shown by default.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import mplcursors
import numpy as np

force = np.random.randn(70, 100).cumsum(axis=1)
force -= force.mean(axis=1, keepdims=True)
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))
for i in range(len(force)):
     plt.plot(force[i], alpha=0.2, label=f'force[{i}]')
plt.margins(x=0.01)
cursor = mplcursors.cursor(hover=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: mplcursors showing 70 labeled curves]

If you're working with a Jupyter notebook, you might need `%matplotlib nbagg` or `%matplotlib qt` instead of `%matplotlib inline` to enable interactivity.