# Python - Scatter Plot - How to plot repeating X values with multiple Y values

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

How do I go about plotting a scatter plot if I have a data frame where column A has repeating values. See image below

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Manager | 200 |
| Manager | 150 |
| Associate | 200 |
| Manager | 150 |

So I want the scatter plot X axis to show column A but only shows once per value. I only want to show
Manager once and then the Y axis would show the 150 and 200 as different circles

I was thinking creating a list or dictionary from my data frame for each of the column A values but was not really sure how to go about it.

I also have over 100+ x axis values. Is there a way to just use a legend and now show the x axis. So this would need a different color for each x axis value.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to enable others to help you.

Comment: A scatter plot will be expecting two quantitative (numeric) variables. This is more like a bar plot since Column A is categorical. That may not help answer your question, but it may help guide your Google searches. :)

Comment: 100+ different legend entries would be very horrible.  Also, it is hard to get more than about 10 easily distinguishable colors.  You can rotate the x-labels (and use a smaller font) if you really really want to show 100+ values.  To easily create a scatter plot from your data, the seaborn library can help, e.g. `ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='column A', y='column B')`

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Of course I have no data of yours, so I have to construct my `a`, containing names and my `b`, containing multiples of 10, possibly $$$...

I decided to place the names in the tick labels and in mouse-hover labels — if the tick labels, for a large no. of names, stick together you can just remove completely, see the code.

The mouse-hover stuff is lifted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47166787/2749397), that you may upvote if you think, as I do, that's a useful example.

The code is commented, but I'll be glad to address any clarification request.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
from itertools import product

# Those 2 functions are lifted (stolen?) from the answer
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/47166787/2749397 by
# https://stackoverflow.com/users/4124317/importanceofbeingernest
# Visit to learn how it works (and upvote if you like it!)

def update_annot(ind):
    pos = sc.get_offsets()[ind["ind"][0]]
    annot.xy = pos
    text = "\n".join("(%s,%d)"%(a[n],b[n]) for n in ind["ind"])
    annot.set_text(text)
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_edgecolor(sc.cmap(sc.norm(c[ind["ind"][0]])))

def hover(event):
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        cont, ind = sc.contains(event)
        if cont:
            update_annot(ind)
            annot.set_visible(True)
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        else:
            if vis:
                annot.set_visible(False)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()

# 90 different names, 400 data points
N_different_names, N_points = 90, 400
# How many names on tick labels?
Max_different_names = 100

# generate a random list of names
a = np.random.choice([''.join(t) for t in product("ABCDE", repeat=5)], N_different_names)
# and place at random these names in a longer list
a = [a[i] for i in np.random.randint(N_different_names, size=N_points)]

# the b array will contain the (?) salaries, unit is $ 10
b_min, b_max = 15, 50
b = np.random.randint(b_min, b_max+1, size=N_points)*10

# sorting the names is optional
sort_names = True
if sort_names:
    a, b = zip(*sorted([t for t in zip(a,b)]))

# we need a list of numbers to convert to colors, I
# arbitrarily choose to set each item to the position of the
# name on the x-axis — it works for sorted or non-s. `a` array
c, d, i = [], {}, 0
for name in a:
    if name not in d: 
        d[name] = i
        i +=1
    c.append(d[name])
del d

# plot the points, rotate and scale the x tick labels
# I'd say that the labels are OK up to ~100 different names
# note the WIDE figsize to accomodate all the x tick labels
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11,6))
sc = ax.scatter(a, b, edgecolor='lightgray',
                c=c, s=100, cmap='winter')

if N_different_names>Max_different_names:
    ax.set_xticks([])
else:
    for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
        label.set(rotation=75, fontsize='xx-small')

# place a dummy annotation and set our callback (also "lifted" as above)
annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0,0), xytext=(20,20),textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round,pad=0.6", fc="w", linewidth=8, alpha=0.75),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
annot.set_visible(False)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)

# That's all Folks!
plt.show()
```