# save plot with hovering annotations option

Tags: python, matplotlib, mousehover, mplcursors

Following this thread:

[How to add hovering annotations to a plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/how-to-add-hovering-annotations-to-a-plot)

example.py

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(1)

x = np.random.rand(15)
y = np.random.rand(15)
names = np.array(list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNO"))
c = np.random.randint(1,5,size=15)

norm = plt.Normalize(1,4)
cmap = plt.cm.RdYlGn

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
sc = plt.scatter(x,y,c=c, s=100, cmap=cmap, norm=norm)

annot = ax.annotate("", xy=(0,0), xytext=(20,20),textcoords="offset points",
                    bbox=dict(boxstyle="round", fc="w"),
                    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->"))
annot.set_visible(False)

def update_annot(ind):
    
    pos = sc.get_offsets()[ind["ind"][0]]
    annot.xy = pos
    text = "{}, {}".format(" ".join(list(map(str,ind["ind"]))), 
                           " ".join([names[n] for n in ind["ind"]]))
    annot.set_text(text)
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_facecolor(cmap(norm(c[ind["ind"][0]])))
    annot.get_bbox_patch().set_alpha(0.4)
    

def hover(event):
    vis = annot.get_visible()
    if event.inaxes == ax:
        cont, ind = sc.contains(event)
        if cont:
            update_annot(ind)
            annot.set_visible(True)
            fig.canvas.draw_idle()
        else:
            if vis:
                annot.set_visible(False)
                fig.canvas.draw_idle()

fig.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", hover)

plt.show()
```

I have managed to create a graph with points that when the mouse hovers it shows the point like this:

[image: hover example]

But when I tried to save it, the hovering option has gone. Based on the code(in the thread) I can only assume that it is interactive, the program should stay running for the hovering option to be displayed.

Is there a method that I can save the data for hovering options? Maybe even an online option that takes some sort of CSV or DataFrame.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share your code. Do you need it to be interactive? If not, check out the [annotations documentation for Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/annotations.html).

Comment: it's the same code from the thread... 

I do need it to be interactive, I have large data if the annotations will be shown in the picture they will cover the data itself, and I don't want that.

Comment: My point is that if you know which points you want to annotate, you can achieve that simply with another code block using minimal code from the documentation. If you need to keep it interactive because you’re annotating lots of specific points, then the solution will be more complex.

Comment: You can have interactive plots on a webpage via the plotly or bokey libraries.

Comment: Do you have any references or some sort of guidelines?