# 3D Matplotlib Scatter Plot Label When Hovering over data point

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib

I am new to matplotlib/python in general and created a simple 3d scatterplot using matplotlib. I'm able to generate the scatter plot but now I want to have the names of each point show up when the mouse hovers over it. The names will come from the dataset I'm using:

df is the dataframe

```
z = df['est_diameter_max']
x = df['miss_distance']
y = df['relative_velocity']
n = df['name']


fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20,17))
ax = plt.axes(projection ="3d")

ax.xaxis.set_pane_color((0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
ax.yaxis.set_pane_color((0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
ax.zaxis.set_pane_color((0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

ax.xaxis.line.set_color("red")
ax.yaxis.line.set_color("green")
ax.zaxis.line.set_color("white")

ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red')  # only affects
ax.tick_params(axis='y', colors='green')  # tick labels
ax.tick_params(axis='z', colors='white')  # not tick marks

ax.scatter3D(x, y, z, color = "white")
ax.set_facecolor("black")

plt.title("Hazardous Near Earth Objects that Missed (2020-2022)", fontweight ='bold')
ax.set_xlabel('Missed Distance in KM', fontweight ='bold', color='red') 
ax.set_ylabel('Velocity Relative to Earth', fontweight ='bold', color='green') 
ax.set_zlabel('Estimate Max Diameter in KM', fontweight ='bold', color='white')

plt.show()
```

Any code I could find online, but it either does nothing or gives me error messages I don't understand. I fear this is above my capabilities, but I think I can understand it if explained to me.

Comment: If you want an off-the-shelf solution, the `plotly` library has this sort of interactivity built in. It's different to `matplotlib` (which is what you've used above). Example from their website: https://plotly.com/python/line-and-scatter/

Comment: Thank you for the link! I'm not sure if it is possible to do what I am asking using matplotlib because I have not found any sort of information on it yet. Everything I'm finding is using plotly or other ones. I'm thinking I will need to change it, but I was hoping I wouldn't have to. I got very attached to this one lol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add hovering annotations to a plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/how-to-add-hovering-annotations-to-a-plot)

Comment: Thank you for the link! This one is for 2D and I was trying to do this for a 3D. Unfortunately, I'm not python-savvy enough to convert that code to use for a 3D scatter plot. I am working on a way around it.