# Mouseover annotation/highlight of seaborn `pairplot`

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, mplcursors

For the sake of mcve, I build the following `pairplot`:

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import HDBSCAN
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np ; np.random.seed(0)

centers = 4
data, c = make_blobs(n_samples    = 20, 
                     centers      = centers, 
                     n_features   = 3,
                     cluster_std  = np.random.rand(centers) * 2.5,
                     random_state = 0)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

alg = HDBSCAN()
alg.fit(df)
df['Label'] = alg.labels_.astype(str)

g = sns.pairplot(df, hue = 'Label')
```

Simple `pairplot`, shows a few outliers, has an underlying `DataFrame` `df`.

What I want is for the functionality to show an annotation of `df.index` for a point on hovering over it, and to somehow highlight that point in all of the other plots.

I have found the hover-over annotation methodology [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/how-to-add-hovering-annotations-to-a-plot) for the underlying `matplotlib.pyplot` objects, but the code there doesn't seem very extensible to a multi-`ax` `figure` like the `pairplot` above.

I have done this with `mplcursors` which gives me the labels (but only by including an additional package)

```
def show_hover_panel(get_text_func=None):
    cursor = mplcursors.cursor(hover=2)    
    if get_text_func:
        cursor.connect(
                event = "add",
                func  = lambda sel: sel.annotation.set_text(get_text_func(sel.index)),
                       )  
    return cursor


def on_add(index):
    print(index)
    ix = df.index[index]
    #size = np.zeros(df.shape[0])
    #size[index] = 1
    #g.map_upper(sns.scatterplot, size = size)
    #g.map_lower(sns.scatterplot, size = size)
    return "{}".format(ix)

show_hover_panel(on_add)
```

The commented out part of the code is my (very) unsuccessful attempt to make it highlight all the related points.  I leave the fairly comical output as an exercise to the reader.

[This example](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/paired_highlight.html) shows how to link highlights via `mplcursors`, but requires every point be its own artist, which is incompatible with `seaborn`.

Is there any smarter way to do a multi-axis highlight, preferably doing it and the multi-axis annotation natively in `matplotlib` and `seaborn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested with Seaborn 0.13.2 (and 0.12.2) and matplotlib 3.8.3.

[mplcursors](https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is remarkably versatile. For one, the cursor can be connected to elements from different subplots. In the case of the pairplot, we want the scatter dots which are stored in `ax.collections[0]`. Provided there are no `NaN` values, the dots remain in the same order as in the dataframe.  `sel.index` is the index into the scatter dot collection, which can be used to indes the dataframe. Also, extra highlighted elements can be added to `sel.extras`. That way, they will be automatically removed when a new point is selected.

Note that mplcursors is a very light-weight library, but reproducing its functionality is a huge amount of work. If you don't want to import it, you can also just drop its only python file into your source directory.

The code below starts from the mpg dataset, with the NaN values removed. Colors are chosen to clearly see the highlighted point in the diverse subplots.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import mplcursors

def show_annotation(sel):
    row = mpg.iloc[sel.index]  # selected row from the dataframe
    sel.annotation.set_text(f"{row['name']} ({row.origin} {row.model_year})\nmpg: {row.mpg}  hp:{row.horsepower}")
    sel.annotation.get_bbox_patch().set(fc="lightsalmon", alpha=0.9)
    for ax in g.axes.flat:
        if len(ax.collections) > 0:
            sel.extras.append(
                ax.scatter(*ax.collections[0].get_offsets()[sel.index], ec='red', fc='none', lw=3, s=50))

mpg = sns.load_dataset('mpg').dropna()

g = sns.pairplot(mpg, vars=['mpg', 'horsepower', 'weight', 'model_year'], hue='origin', palette='pastel')

cursor = mplcursors.cursor([ax.collections[0] for ax in g.axes.flat if len(ax.collections) > 0], hover=True)
cursor.connect("add", show_annotation)
plt.show()
```

[image: mplcursors with sns.pairgrid and highlighting in subplots]

Comment: Unfortunately the code provided when applied to my toy problem (fixing the first two lines of `show_annotation` to avoid over-writing `df` and setting the `sel.annotation.set_text` line to just print the index) seems to do nothing.  No annotation, no highlighting, no nothing.  Hacking a print statement into `show_annotation` makes it look like the code is never called when hovering over the plot.

Comment: problem seems to be in `[ax.collections[0] for ax in g.axes.flat if len(ax.collections) == 1]`, that list is always empty so nothing else happens.  `ax.collections` is always an `Axes.ArtistList` of 0 or 4 collections in your toy problem.  Unfortunately I haven't the foggiest idea what you're trying to do there to try to fix it >.<

Comment: It seems seaborn 0.12 has some extra dummy collections into the ax.  The test was meant to skip the diagonal axes, so the test can be changed to `len(ax.collections) > 0` while still using `ax.collections[0]` to get all the scatter dots on a subplot.

Comment: That works!  Can you edit it into the answer?