# How to get the exact coordinates of a marker with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, google-maps-markers

Im am working with a data base and charts. My problem is that i need to see in the charts where markers are. I need to see it precisely. I ve been looking for it for a while, but found nothing.
[image]

This is the kinf of graph im working with at the moment and below i leave my block of code. Most lines are commented because they are rather part of the DB connection or work with its data. So i ve written manually some values.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime




fechas = []
fechas_string = ['01/01/2024','02/01/2024','07/01/2024']
result_1=[2,4,1]


def convertTuple(tup):
    str = ''.join(tup) #Funcion encargada de convertir las tuplas en strings
    return str

def conexion_Db():
    try:
        #sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('webscrap.db') #Conexion a base de datos
        #cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor() #Defino un cursor que me permite interactuar con la BD
        print('Base Iniciada')
        #query_1 = '''SELECT asd FROM Products''' #Defino una consulta para poder reutilizarla en algun momento
        #query_2 = '''SELECT otro_numero FROM Products''' #Igual que la consulta anterior
        #cursor.execute(query_1) #.execute ejecuta la consulta
        #result_1 = cursor.fetchall() #Guarda la informacion que tiene cursor en este caso en result_1
        #cursor.execute(query_2)
        #result_2 = cursor.fetchall()
        #fechas_string="" #Lo uso despues como variable temporal
        #fechas=[] #Aca se guardan las fechas en formato fecha dd/mm/yy
        #for x in result_2:                                              #En este for convierto las tuplas dentro de las listas en strings. Es necesario porque vienen en formato tupla y aparentemente el grafico no es capaz de interpretarlas
            #fechas_string=convertTuple(x)                               #Ademas cambio los strings a formato fecha y despues las agrego a la lista con .append
            #fechas.append(datetime.strptime(fechas_string, '%d/%m/%Y')) 
        for x in fechas_string:
            fechas.append(datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y')) 
        
        plt.plot(fechas, result_1, color="red", linestyle="dashed", linewidth= 3, marker=".", markerfacecolor="green", markersize=10) #Customizacion del grafico
        plt.xlabel('Eje X') #Mas customizaciones
        plt.ylabel('Eje Y')
        plt.title('Primer Grafico')
        plt.show() #Para mostrar el grafico


    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print('Error occurred - ', error)

    finally:
    
        #if sqliteConnection:
            #sqliteConnection.close()
            print('SQl Connection closed')
conexion_Db()
```

I also accept any suggestion you would like to point :D

Comment: The markers are dependent on your x and y data. So specifically at x=2024-01-01 and y=2, x=2024-01-02 and y=4, and x=2024-01-07 and y=1.

Comment: Yes i know. But in this example there are only 3 markers and with pretty similar values. I want to know the exact position beacause i might have non integrer numbers or just big numbers that are shown exactly

Comment: Then it isnt possible to show it graphically? for example when you pass by a marker with your cursor?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/how-to-add-hovering-annotations-to-a-plot) might be useful if you're looking for hovering annotations.

Comment: TY thats exactly what im looking for. :D awesome