# Jupyter Lab in AWS SageMaker | Interactive Visualizations | Unable to display Tool Tip when Hover over Data Points

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-lab, annotate

Followed [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908636/how-to-add-hovering-annotations-to-a-plot) which guides with example code for building scatter plot with Annotations. This worked like a charm in Jupyter Notebook.

When Tried the same code in Jupyter Lab unable to run it with the following error:

```
ImportError: libGl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Upon researching a bit, understood that from Generative AI's response that `PyQt5` isn't directly compatible with running within JupyterLab because JupyterLab primarily focuses on web-based interactive computing, and `PyQt5` is designed for desktop GUI applications. "

Can someone help here, is there a way we can generate Interactive visualizations with tool tips displayed when hovered over the data points.

Generate Interactive visualizations with tool tips displayed when hovered over the data points.